# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create webview

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, webview, cordova-plugin-proguard

I am working on ionic v1 project.My problem is - after updating the android platform version to latest - 8.0.0, the app crashes on launch.

Getting this error on logcat-

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tv.gpd/com.tv.gpd.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create webview.
```

I am using this command to add latest android platform-

```
ionic cordova platform add android@latest
```

I did some digging and found some solutions and I tried it-

1)Add below line of code in proguard-custom.txt

```
# These clases contain references to cordova webView
-keep class com.ionicframework.cordova.webview.** {*; }
-keep class com.ionicframework.cordova.webview.*
```

2)Also checked it by downgrading the "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" plugin to - 1.2.1
previously webview version is - 2.3.2

I am working with -

```
Ionic 3.19.0
Cordova CLI 7.0.0
Cordova-Android 8.0.0
```

Any help will be appreciated as I need to make app to support Android latest - Oreo and Pie version.

Thanks

Comment: Anyone facing this issue.Please help me

Comment: use cordova-plugin-proguard

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this also
 If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
 and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface

```
-keepclassmembers class android.webkit.WebView {
   public *;
}
```

Comment: I uncomment the code from my proguard-custom.txt.
But I am not getting this line - specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface.

Which class name I have to specify?

Comment: copy upper coide

Comment: Yes,I have the exact same code in proguard-custom.txt.
But still my app crashing with same error.

Comment: I didn't have issue when running app in debug mode. It was crashing only in release mode.
I didn't have to add this particular line but I was missing proguard rules file in general. I added the file and it started working.